# Remove duplication in a Makefile: Target files are written once under Phony variable `all` and again as recipe targets

Tags: makefile

Below I have copied an example of a Makefile for executing some scripts to clean and merge data.

This Makefile format requires me to list each target file twice: once under `all` and once as the target of  each recipe. As the makefile gets long I sometimes forget to add new targets to `all` after creating a new recipe.

Without an `all` variable Make will only build the first target and its prerequisites.

**How can I remove this source of duplication from my Makefile and still have all recipe targets checked and rebuilt if their prerequisites change?**

```
DIR_DATA = ./data
DIR_RAW = $(DIR_DATA)/raw
DIR_MUNGE = ./munge

VPATH = $(DIR_RAW) $(DIR_DATA) $(DIR_MUNGE)

########################################################   
####################### Recipes ########################
########################################################

ds_mtcars.rds: ds_mtcars.R ds_mt_raw.csv
    Rscript $<

ds_mt_agg.rds: ds_mt_agg.R ds_mtcars.rds
    Rscript $<

ds_mt_temp.rds: ds_mt_temp.R ds_mtcars.rds ds_mt_agg.rds
    Rscript $<

########################################################   
####################### Phony vars #####################
########################################################    

.Phony: all 

all: ds_mtcars.rds ds_mt_agg.rds ds_mt_temp.rds 

clean: 
  rm -f ./data/*.rds
```

Answer (score 1):

Often, you can avoid such duplication by using patterns and lists.   In your case, because the dependencies do not seem to follow a simple pattern, you have to explicitly define any unique dependencies associated with a file.   Assuming that each `.rds` depends on the corresponding `.R` file, you could eliminate some of the duplication using a static pattern rule as follows:

```
RDS_FILES := ds_mtcars.rds ds_mt_agg.rds ds_mt_temp.rds

all:

# define any unique dependencies explicitly:
ds_mtcars.rds: ds_mt_raw.csv
ds_mt_agg.rds: ds_mtcars.rds
ds_mt_temp.rds: ds_mtcars.rds ds_mt_agg.rds

# use Static pattern rule -- 
#  explicit dependencies will be stacked
$(RDS_FILES) : %.rds : %.R
    Rscript $<

.Phony: all
all: $(RDS_FILES)
```

You would still have to list each target with special dependencies in both the starting list (`RDS_LIST`), and in the special dependency rules.